# get date value for db in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am storing from-date and to-date in my sqlite db in 2012-02-15 00:02:03 format. Now how can retrieve this. I tried with the following query .. where did i go wrong.

```
select category,sum(amount)  from inbox where  strftime(currentdate) > strftime(fastdate)
```

it shows error. can any one help me to solve this

Comment: What kind of error? Be specific.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:   syntax error:

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "00": syntax error: , while compiling: select category,sum(amount)  from inbox where  accno ='2754' and category ='Un Categorised' and strftime(2012-7-13 00:00:00) > strftime(2011-7-13 00:00:00)

Comment: i am using StringBuilder to create query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using strftime correctly.

`strftime('format', 'time')`

It takes a format and a string version of the time. You are not putting the time in as a string at all.

You can see all the different formats and some examples [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Your comparison should look like this...

strftime('%s','currentdate') > strftime('%s','fastdate')

Comment: sorry i did mistake. i write like this. this query was working  select category,sum(amount)  from inbox where  accno ='0004' and category ='Un Categorised' and strftime(fromtime) > date('now','-1 year')

Comment: What? I don't think you understand, thats not at all how you need to change it.